# template string and function concatenation

Tags: json, go, go-templates

I try to template some JSON values in a go function, which basically works like I expect it.
But if I try to concatenate the template string with a template function it fails (with different errors, depends on how the template string looks)

For example, I have the following line:

```json
{"APPLICATION_HOST":"http://{{ .NAMESPACE }}-repo.{{ .NAMESPACE }}:3004"}
```

Templating works and gives following output:

> {"APPLICATION_HOST":"http://test-repo.test:3004"}

I now want to encode the value with base64, and tried for example the following:

```json
{"APPLICATION_HOST":"{{ http://{{ .NAMESPACE }}-repo.{{ .NAMESPACE }}:3004 | b64encode }}"}
```

That gives the error:

> "http://" is not a fuction

If I just do something like the following (which looks hideous):

```json
{"APPLICATION_HOST":"{{ printf "http://{{ .NAMESPACE }}-repo.{{ .NAMESPACE }}:3004"|b64encode }}"}
```

It outputs the following:

> {"APPLICATION_HOST":"aHR0cDovL3t7IC5OQU1FU1BBQ0UgfX0tcmVwby57eyAuTkFNRVNQQUNFIH19OjMwMDQ="}

What decodes to:

> http://{{ .NAMESPACE }}-repo.{{ .NAMESPACE }}:3004

Template function looks like that currently:

```golang
func generateDefinitionJson(filePath string, bodyBytes []byte) (interface{}, error) {
    var (
        tpl             bytes.Buffer
        err             error
        tplInterface, m map[string]interface{}
    )
    funcMap := template.FuncMap{
        // The name "b64encode" is what the function will be called in the template text.
        "b64encode": b64encode,
  }
    // read definition file
    fileContent, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filePath)
    // load definition as template
    t, err := template.New("").Funcs(funcMap).Parse(string(fileContent))
    if err != nil {
        logger.Error("Parsing Template failed: " + err.Error())
    } else {
        // create value map
        err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(bodyEscaped), &m)
        mInterfaceStr := fmt.Sprintf("%v", m)
        if err != nil {
            logger.Error("Failed to create Value Map: " + err.Error())
        } else {
            // execute template mapping
            err = t.Execute(&tpl, m)
            logger.Debug(tpl.String())
            if err != nil {
                logger.Error("Templating failed: " + err.Error())
            }
            // unmarshal template into interface
            err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(tpl.String()), &tplInterface)
            if err != nil {
                logger.Error("Couldn't Unmarshal definition to interface: " + err.Error())
            }
        }
    }
    return tplInterface, err
}

func b64encode(str string) string {
    return base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(str))
}
```

Does anyone has an idea how to solve that issue?

Comment: Generating JSON via text/template is a bad idea. Use encoding/json.

Comment: Or if this is in Helm (not that this example seems to be...), use the [toJson](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#type-conversion-functions) function.

Comment: @Volker do you have an example for your recommendation, because I checked the encoding/json package documentation and can not see any function which would act as template engine

Comment: encoding/json.Marshal _is_ the template engine with templates being structs or maps.

Answer (score 3):

`printf` does not do template expansion of `{{ .NAMESPACE }}`, for example. Instead, it expands `%s` and related verbs. This means that

```
{"APPLICATION_HOST":"{{ printf "http://{{ .NAMESPACE }}-repo.{{ .NAMESPACE }}:3004"|b64encode }}"}
```

should be

```
{"APPLICATION_HOST":"{{ printf "http://%s-repo.%s:3004" .NAMESPACE .NAMESPACE |b64encode }}"}
```

But the *proper* answer is to use proper JSON marshaling instead, so that you're certain that valid JSON is produced, and that any unusual characters are properly escaped, etc.